# Converting a mongdb collection to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

Hi I am trying to convert a mongodb collection to array and its not working giving me blank array any help would be appreciated playingCollection is mongodb collection.

```
var state = [];

playingCollection.find({},function(err, companies) {
    companies.each(function(err,company){
            if (company !== null) {
                var obj = company.playername;
                state.push(obj);
            }
        }
    );
});

console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an asynchronous call.

If you log it inside the callback, it shouldn't be empty:

```
playingCollection.find({},function(err, companies) {
    companies.each(function(err,company){
            if (company !== null) {
                var obj = company.playername;
                state.push(obj);
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(state); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toArray`

```
playingCollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, companies)
```

Comment: still blank, however just a fyi if do console.log(obj) instead of state.push(obj); it works fine and prints all the elements